# Multiple Criteria Pandas Dataframe - Python

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have a list of 'topics' I want to count below

```
topic_list = ['Topic 1','Topic 2','Topic 3', 'Topic 4']
```

And I have the following dataframe below.

```
TEXT      | USER    | ID
----------|---------|------
Topic 1   | User 1  | 100
Topic 2   | User 1  | 100
Topic 3   | User 2  | 150
Topic 4   | User 2  | 150
Topic 2   | User 2  | 150
Topic 1   | User 3  | 200
Topic 3   | User 3  | 200
Topic 2   | User 1  | 100
Topic 4   | User 2  | 150
```

The expected/desired output that I would like is the following below, where I want to know the sum of unique user's IDs who have the corresponding text amount using my topic_list as the key.

```
TEXT      | ID
----------|-------
Topic 1   | 300
Topic 2   | 250
Topic 3   | 350
Topic 4   | 150
```

Is there a way to do this in Python 2.7?

Answer (score 2):

Use `drop_duplicates` + `groupby`:

```
df.drop_duplicates(['TEXT','USER']).groupby('TEXT', as_index=False).ID.sum()

      TEXT   ID
0  Topic 1  300
1  Topic 2  250
2  Topic 3  350
3  Topic 4  150
```